Should the tag "charcter" be removed?
I failed to see any point of the tag charcter. Should it be removed, or at least be combined with the tag characters?

Surely it's just a typo.  I edited the two questions with the charcter tag, so it's gone now.

I proposed charcter as a synonym for characters. You can vote on it here.
